# <ObjectAttribute title="{i8>detailAttributeabc}" text="{efg/Value}" /> here how can i make the text in italic format

Tags: javascript, xml, html, webstorm

`<ObjectAttribute text="{Description}"  />`

How can I make the text in italic format?

`<i>` this tag is not working in this code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Check it: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: XML does not have styling, so no use of *italic* markup